# PHP Regexp with variable in string to search

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I'm in need of a regexp that will allow me to retrieve all the following data from a php source file :

```
MUI('Some text')
MUI("Some text", $lang)
```

The regexp is used to extract all the terms enclosed in MUI("...") in a php file in order to build a list of items to translate.
I already have the regexp for the first case :

```
MUI("Some text") > $pattern = '/MUI\((["\'].*?)["\']\)/';
```

But I had to add a parameter which is a variable and since then my regexp wont find the second case

```
MUI("Some text", $lang).
```

Please be aware that the text to find may be enclosed by ' or ".
Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not really possible in a robust manner. Reason is that regular expressions as a tool are not mighty enough for the task. You might be able to get a working solution, but actually that would only be _usually_ working. It is easy to demonstrate situations where the solution will fail. For example something like that: `MUI("Some ) text", $lang)`. What you actually need as a tool is not regular expressions, but a language parser that is able to understand the actual structure of a valid PHP file.

Comment: See `MUI\((?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2wVQe/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just curious, can't it be as simple as [this](https://regex101.com/r/LehN7X/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Seems to work in your demo. I'll try it live in a few and will keep you posted. Thx for your input.

Comment: @nice_dev [It cannot](https://regex101.com/r/LehN7X/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok but I would rather assume OP's issue to be straightforward unless he mentions the same. Ideally OP would need to make the syntax uniform for a much simpler regex.

Comment: @nice_dev It is clear the quotation marks are used as delimiters and delimiters need to be escaped to be used as literal chars inside such string literals. It is much safer to consider such cases in such scenarios.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Fair enough. I used to do the same before trying to add validations to my answers here on SO but I was told that I was simply speculating, so I had stopped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?s)MUI\((?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J2wVQe/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - `.` now matches any chars including line break chars
- `MUI\(` - `MUI(` string
- `(?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)')` - Branch reset group matching either:

  - `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - a double quote string literal (capturing what is in between quotes into Group 1)
  - `|` - or
  - `'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'` - a single quote string literal (capturing what is in between quotes into Group 1 - yes, still Group 1 since this is an alternative inside a branch reset group).

Comment: thx for your input. I've tried it but PHP throws an exception :

$pattern = '/(?s)MUI\((?|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|\'([^\'\\]*(?:\\.[^\'\\]*)*)\')/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$Content,$matches);

preg_match_all():Compilation failed : missing terminating ] at offset 60.

Any ideas on the trouble, maybe PHP needs some kind of escaping ?

Comment: @BlackPage In PHP, it must be defined as `$regex = '~MUI\((?|"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"|\'([^\'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*)\')~s';`